# Como pudo ordenar esta consulta, quiero ordenarlo por el alias (creadoHace)

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT destinatario.contactid as destinocontact,CONCAT('Creado hace ',datediff(DATE(NOW()),DATE(y.biz_dateadd)),' dias') as creadoHace,CONCAT(creator.firstname,' ', creator.lastname) as creador ,CONCAT(destinatario.firstname,' ',destinatario.lastname) as destino, CONCAT(empresa.accountname) as empresa, Y.*
        from (
        SELECT destinatario.contactid,MAX(n.notesid) as notesid
                from vtiger_notes as n
                inner join vtiger_contactdetails as creator on creator.contactid=n.biz_contact
                inner join vtiger_senotesrel as sn on sn.notesid=n.notesid
                inner join vtiger_contactdetails as destinatario on destinatario.contactid=sn.crmid
                where creator.accountid=717 and creator.isComercial='1' 
                and n.biz_type<>'Creacion contacto' and n.biz_contact = 644075
                group by destinatario.contactid
        ) as x inner join vtiger_notes as y on x.notesid = y.notesid        
                inner join vtiger_contactdetails as creator on creator.contactid=y.biz_contact
                inner join vtiger_senotesrel as sn on sn.notesid=y.notesid
                inner join vtiger_contactdetails as destinatario on destinatario.contactid=sn.crmid
                inner join vtiger_account as empresa on empresa.accountid=destinatario.accountid    
                where creator.accountid= 717 and creator.isComercial='1'            
                and y.biz_type<>'No tomará el servicio'
                and y.biz_estado ='1'
                and y.biz_type<>'Creacion contacto' and datediff(DATE(NOW()),DATE(y.biz_dateadd)) > 7
```

Comment: Añadiendo al final `ORDER BY creadoHace`. Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de la tabla en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado quieres obtener e incorpora el código de tus intentos (utiliza Ctrl+k para el código). Preferimos enseñarte a pescar que darte peces, si vemos lo que has intentado, podremos ayudarte a mejorar. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]

Answer (score 1):

Agrega `order by(creadoHace)`, si en algún punto necesitas verlo de forma decendente agrega `order by(creadoHace, 'DESC')`

Comment: gracias por responder pero por algun razon me esta ordenando por grupos  me explico digamos que tengo distintas notas creadas hace 30 dias en un grupo me ordena de 10 a 1 y en el otro de 30 a 10 Ej    10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20 asi lo esta ordenando por que pasa esto

Answer (score 0):

ya resolví este error 
cambiando el  order by(creadoHace, 'DESC') por order by (datediff(DATE(NOW()),DATE(y.biz_dateadd)),'DESC')